# Context menu item

Tags: click, element, katalon-studio

I have created a test case to click a context menu item in Katalon.

Expect result- 
Once the item is clicked, a new page should open in the same browser page to enter text data.

What I see-
test results show item click as pass but the new page is not being loaded and so steps after that are all failing.

If I manually click then the new page opens and the test steps pass. 
I have used java script query for clicking the context menu item. 
Any suggestions why it isn't working?

Code I have written in Katalon -

WebUI.waitForPageLoad(300)
WebUI.waitForElementVisible(findTestObject('EventProperties/a_Event'), 100)
CustomKeywords.'com.ea.utilities.CommonUtilities.clickUsingJS'(findTestObject('EventProperties/a_Event'), 0)
WebUI.waitForPageLoad(700)

I have written the xpath for the Test object a_event. 
The test results are successfully till the a_event is clicked. But this click is not opening the new page in the browser. So the next line in test case  - Set text -- input event name is failing as this field is on the new page.

[Test steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnXhm.png)
[Test Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEpSp.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit the question to provide a) your code as it stands, b) what you expect to see, c) what you are seeing in practice, d) any error messages you are getting. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks MandyShaw. I have added more details, code and error messages as well. I have seen the other related posts but in those the item is not visible or not getting clicked but in my case, element is visible and getting clicked but the page after the element click is not loading.

Comment: I have changed the code and now the test fails at finding the context menu item.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully someone will now be able to help you (unfortunately I am not familiar with katalon).

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your test results screenshot, the actual "click" is not executed (even if the steps are in green). That's a common problem i get with Katalon, and it happens when it fails to identify the requested object. As you can see in the screenshot, it says "Web element found by heuristic method is **not used**..."

The line before says that an object was found by it's tag, type and class, but in my experience this is not enough. You should edit your identifiers and ONLY use xpath or eventually it's id. This usually solves this kinda problems.